# KEIL with STM32f4xx

Tags: keil

I installed keil uvision db-arm debugger version 5.16a. And Creating the new project it does not including "driver software pack". How I add "driver pack"?

[image: Driver Image]

Answer (score 0):

What kind of drivers would you like to install? Are you referring to JTAG/SWD debug hardware?

In this case, this usually comes together with the hardware.